# Assistance with a T-SQL JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I have two tables, call them Singles and Averages.

Singles is:

```
PersonID (PK)
EventID (FK)
best
worldRank
```

Averages is:

```
PersonID (PK)
EventID (FK)
best
worldRank
```

I'm trying to combine these two tables.
Basically, the resulting table should be:

"Merge is:

```
PersonID (PK)
EventID(FK)
bestSingle ('best' from Singles)
bestAverage ('best' from Averages)
worldRankSingle ('worldRank' from Singles)
worldRankAverage ('worldRank' from Averages)"
```

Here's what I have right now.

```
SELECT  RanksAverage.[personId],
RanksAverage.[eventId],
RanksAverage.[best] AS 'averageBest',
RanksAverage.[worldRank] AS 'averageRank',
RanksSingle.best AS 'singleBest',
RanksSingle.worldRank AS 'singleRank'

FROM [cubing].[dbo].[WCA_export_RanksSingle] AS RanksSingle

JOIN [cubing].[dbo].[WCA_export_RanksAverage] AS RanksAverage
ON RanksAverage.personId = RanksSingle.personId
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012, by the way.

Comment: What's unsatisfactory with your current effort? Looks like a good query to me. What's wrong with it? That is - what exactly do you need assistance with?

Comment: It ends up as having 200 records with the same PersonID.

Comment: Please don't use `AS 'alias'` syntax. Use `AS [alias]` syntax when required, but in this case those aliases don't need to be delimited in either way. Using single quotes for aliases is deprecated *plus* it makes them look like string literals.

Comment: Are you trying to get one row per event, one row per person, or something else? Could you show a few rows of sample data and desired results, so that other than reverse engineering your join, we know where the data is coming from and what you want to get out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the only thing you're missing from your `JOIN` is the second criteria for `event`:

```
JOIN [cubing].[dbo].[WCA_export_RanksAverage] AS RanksAverage
ON RanksAverage.personId = RanksSingle.personId
AND RanksAverage.eventId = RanksSingle.eventId
```

This is just an assumption because we don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable assumption, though without knowing what the OP is trying to get out, it is just that - an assumption.

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing!
I had a double-join going earlier. I didn't know you could AND in a join...thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Aaaand... assumption wins ;)